# .NET Standard 2.0 - Which Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions Version to Use

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

I've created a .NET Standard 2.0 class library which has an extension method that adds service registrations to the IServiceCollection instance. Something like this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Cache.Extensions
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddCacheServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();

            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

In order to reference the type 'IServiceCollection' I was prompted to install the 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions' package. Version 2.2.0 was installed into my .NET standard library. When I created a NuGet package for my library and a user tried to install it in their ASP.NET Core 2.1 web application, they got an error indicating they had to use a version of 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions' with a version 2.1 or something along those lines. This got me thinking that the version of the 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions' package installed should match the .NET Core version. Is this correct? I was under the assumption the .NET package versions should match the version of the .NET Core app.

So this means referencing 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions' with version 2.2.0 in .NET Standard library stops .NET Core apps with a version of 2.1 from using the app. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm going to try to reproduce this so it's clearer what's going on. Is your NuGet package public?

Comment: The ASP.NET Core version doesn't matter. It's the version of the *package* that matters. A project targeting ASP.NET Core 2.1 will include the 2.1 version of the Microsoft.Extensions packages. If your own package requires the 2.2 extensions, the web app will have to upgrade to the latest version too. If you don't want to force the web app to update, use the 2.1 extensions

Comment: Unfortunately it’s not. I plan on creating a simple version of the package and installing it in both a 2.1 and 2.2 app. I took a look at some GitHub projects that have a similar package which adds to IServiceCollection (MediatR) and they reference the abstractions package 2.0. I've personally used that Mediatr package in both a 2.1 and 2.2 app without issue so maybe something is wrong with our particular project.

Comment: A binding redirect should allow the web app to work with an upgraded version of just the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`. The developers of the web app may not want to do that though, or at least, not without testing first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create an ASP.NET Core 2.1 web application, you get a project file like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` NuGet package version 2.1.11](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.11) depends on `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, with an explicit version constraint of "(>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0)".

If you add a dependency directly to the web application of:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version=">= 2.2.0" />
```

then you end up with one warning (rather than an errror):

```
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 requires
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0)
but version Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.2.0 was resolved.
```

Now I *suspect* that that's fine... but it would be *better* for you to make your library depend on the earliest version (within the same *major* version) of the dependency injection package that contains all the functionality you need. It's unfortunate that Microsoft.AspNetCore.App has an upper bound in the constraint here - it doesn't make much sense (IMO) to pin to a specific minor version, given that 2.2.0 *should* be compatible with 2.1.x, if SemVer has been followed properly. Still, the constraint is there, and that's what's causing the warning.

If 2.0.0 (of the dependency injection abstraction package) contains everything you need, I'd just use that. Each ASP.NET Core web application will use the version that it wants, greater than or equal to 2.0.0, and all should be well for multiple versions of ASP.NET Core, with no warnings.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I think, this is correct.
IMHO, your NuGet-Package are not .Net standard 2.0 if you use another package with .net core 2.1 or 2.2.
See here: [enter link description here][https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/net-standard]

.Net standard 2.0 can also use with .net framework 4.6.1, but if you are use a .net core package, this will not run. So your package are not .net standard compatible.

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions doesn't depend on netcore, it depends on netstandard2.0. It's fine to depend on it from another package targeting netstandard2.0.